# How to get data from the list.stdout.on method

Tags: javascript, node.js

You need to get the names of all sections. But I can't get them out of this method. Please help me
This function gets the names of repositories(disks) C: E: D: and so on. This information is only available inside this function. How do I get it from there?

```
function get_win_drives(success_cb,error_cb){
    var stdout = '';
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
            list  = spawn('cmd');

    list.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        stdout += data;
    });

    list.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    list.on('exit', function (code) {
        if (code == 0) {
            console.log(stdout);
            var data = stdout.split('\r\n');
            data = data.splice(4,data.length - 7);
            data = data.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);
            console.log(data);
            // success_cb(data);
        } else {
            console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
            error_cb();
        }
    });
    list.stdin.write('wmic logicaldisk get caption\n');
    list.stdin.end();
}
```

I also don't understand what kind of data this function asks for as arguments

Comment: it's really hard to understand what you trying to achieve here please be more precise

Comment: I edited the question. Please take a look